# Customizing Django user model to take into account DB non-null marks

Tags: django, orm, django-authentication

I am using Django's standard `django.contrib.auth.models` to implement authorization on my website. I have added a NON-NULL `email` field to my DB `auth_user` table. The problem is that in Django's ORM `email` seems to be nullable. In other words, Django does not respect non-null attribute of DB field in MySQL. Is there any way to tell Django that this field is required as specified in DB, and to make this information reflected when doing `if field.required == True:` check inside a form's `__init__` method?

My models and respective forms look like this:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            if field.required == True:
                field.widget.attrs['required'] = ''
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do anything. EmailFields are stored as varchars, and are set to empty strings rather than null when blank.

If you want to make it required on the form, then do so in that `__init__` method:

```
self.fields['email'].required = True
```

Comment: No, why should you need to do that?

Comment: +++++++++++++++1. `self.fields['email'].required = ''` and `self.fields['email'].required = true` have different functionalities. I understood it only now !!!